# Expand `pwd` inside a vim command

Tags: vimscript

I have a variable that I would set to the current result I get from `:pwd`.

I tried the following, which obviously doesn't work:

`:let b:projectroot = expand("pwd")`

But this is essentially what I want to do. I want to switch to a directory using `:cd` and set that as the value for the variable `b:projectroot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to get the printed output of an Ex command such as `:pwd` is to use the [`execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29) function.

However, in this specific case, you can get the current directory in a more straightforward way by simply calling [`getcwd()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29):

```
let b:projectroot = getcwd()
```

The issue with `execute()` in this particular case is that you get leading whitespace in your result, so you also need to use `trim()` (or another similar string cleanup function) to get only the directory name:

```
let b:projectroot = trim(execute('pwd'))
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time with the `trim` part, thanks!